# Why $(12)=(12)(12)(12)∈S_3$ is not a counter example to given claim.

Tags: permutations

I was assigned the following homework problem over break:

> Let $g \in S_n$. Show that $g$ can be written as a product of at most $n − 1$
>   transpositions.

**Please do not respond with a proof for this claim**, as I would really like to construct it for myself.  What I could really use some help understanding is why the following is not a counter example:

Consider the permutation $g=(12)$ in $S_3$.  It can easily be checked that $(12)=(12)(12)(12)$, so $g$ can be expressed as the product of 3 transpositions, which is clearly greater than $2=3-1$.

This "counter example" has been bugging me for the past few days.  If anyone has any hints on where it fails, I would appreciate that much more than a straight-forward answer.

Comment: The claim says that there *is* a way to write it as a product of at most $n - 1$ transpositions, not that every way to write it is that short.

Comment: Of course--that makes things so much easier to comprehend!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(12)$ is the product of just one transposition, thus fewer than $3$.

The fact that $g$ can be expressed as a product of no more than $n-1$ transpositions does not mean it cannot also be expressed as a product of a much larger number of transpositions.